# rsync in crontab fails with mkstemp: no such file or directory

Tags: server, rsync

I am running the following command in my backup script:

```
rsync -ravv user@serverprod:/home/user/sites/main_site/backup/*.zip /space/backup/main_site/
```

Crontab:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
*       20      *       *       1-5     python /root/scripts/backup/backup.py -S -F main_site
```

I run into a issue every time `rsync` runs in `crontab`, but if I try to run it manually, I see no problem at all. I run as root in both cases.

Error:

```
rsync: mkstemp "/space/backup/main_site/.main_site_2016_01_29_132442250748_a82abb7e57f88c2afedb2e00c022f935c470b9e1_backup.zip.I3kVYl" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Now have in mind that `main_site_2016_01_29_132442250748_a82abb7e57f88c2afedb2e00c022f935c470b9e1_backup` is an expected file name. However, what comes before it, `.` and after `.I3kVYl` are not. I guess this must be temporary files the command creates in order to perform its operations. And the question is: why this error?

I am using Ubuntu server 14.04.4.

Comment: Whats the output of `ls /space/backup/main_site/`?

Comment: The output is the error I pasted: `rsync: mkstemp "/space/backup/main_site/.main_site_2016_01_29_132442250748_a82abb7e57f88c2afedb2e00c022f935c470b9e1_backup.zip.I3kVYl" failed: No such file or directory (2)`. It happens to all files I try to sync.

Comment: Just post the exact output of the exact command i have given.

Comment: I misread your comment. The output are files I previously had in the folder: `main_site_2016_01_28_143920817630_1717b605631740cb8740c34ba7c19135c5959a46_backup.zip main_site_2016_01_28_143920817630_1717b605631740cb8740c34ba7c19135c5959a46_backup.zip.enc` [...].

Comment: Something that is worth mentioning is that I don't see this error when I run directly with the user. It only happens in `crontab`. I'll change the schedule of this task. It might be conflicting with some others I have.

Comment: Still the same damn problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when I tried to sync data with remote FTP server mounted using `curlftpfs`

Probably your `/space/backup` folder is also mounted remote folder

The solution worked for me:

- create temp folder
- indicate to `rsync` which temp folder to use (should be outside of remote destination folder)

  ```
  rsync -T "my_temp_folder_other_than_space/backup" -ravv user@serverprod:/home/user/sites/main_site/backup/*.zip /space/backup/main_site/
  ```